# Regex: Match wildcard followed by variable length of digits

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the personal number from a stringlike `Personal number:    123456` with the following regex:

```
(Personal number|Personalnummer).*(\d{2,10})
```

When trying to get the second group, it will only contain the last 2 digits of the personal number. If I change the digit range to `{3,10}` it will match the last 3 digits of the personal number.

Now I cannot just add the whitespaces as additional group, because I cannot be sure that there will be always whitespaces - there might be none or some other characters, but the personal number will be always at the end.

Is there anyway I could instruct the Parser to get the whole digit string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.*` is working as greedy quantifier for the regex. It ends up eating all the matching characters except the last 2 that it has to leave to match the string.

You have to make it reluctant by applying `?`. Like below

```
(Personal number|Personalnummer).*?(\d{2,10})
```

Now it should work perfectly.

You can also convert the first group into a non capturing group, then you'll get only the number that you want in the answer like below.

```
(?:Personal number|Personalnummer).*?(\d{2,10})
```

Comment: That did it :) Also thanks for the hint with the non capturing group, that just solved another issue :)

Comment: And you can consider beeing more specific, if you know it can be a optional colon and then only blanks `(?:P N|Pn):? *(\d{2,10})` this way it does not have to be reluctant and you are sure you do not lose unexpected stuff. (It is however less tolerant).

Comment: @eckes it will still have to be reluctant. It's `.*` which is eating the numbers.

Comment: @11thdimension thats why my expression has no `.` (but a blank, or maybe a `[:space:]` character class,only.

Comment: I missed that, it's invisible :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a reluctant [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) on the wildcard match (eg `*?`). For instance `.*?` will result in the full numeric expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Personal number|Personalnummer).*?(\\d{2,10})");//note the ?
Matcher m = p.matcher("Personal number:    123456");
if ( m.find() ){
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```